# Open external link in webview

Tags: android, url, webview

Hello My question is this when I pressed a link(URL) for example from whatsapp android asks what browser should open that, and I select my browser and then my app is open but they dont go to the link, they go to the homescreen that is google. How could I do to open the link instead of open google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the Intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

get the Url:

```
String url = intent.getData().toString();
```

and later:

```
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: yes i know that, but i want to recive that in my browser not to send, understand?

Comment: Oh you mean you are writing a Browser? Then you'll have to receive the Intent in your app, and call `webView.loadUrl()` with the data received.

Comment: Yes i want to do that! how i do it?